# Show that if simple graph diameter is bounded then max degree is unbounded

Tags: graph-theory

Im trying to solve exercise 2.3 from Jackson's Social and Economic Networks but I'm making no progress:

*"Consider a sequence of networks such that each network in the sequence is connected and involves more nodes than the previous network. Show that if the diameter of the networks is bounded, then the maximal degree of the networks is unbounded. That is, show that if there exists a finite number M such that the diameter of every network in the sequence is less than M, then for any integer K there exists a network in the sequence and a node in that network that has more than K neighbors."
Jackson, Matthew O.. Social and Economic Networks (Page 52). Princeton University Press. Kindle Edition.*

By networks we mean unweighted and undirected simple graphs.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you making no progress? What have you tried?

Comment: Hint. Show that, if the diameter and degree are both bounded, then the number of nodes is bounded. (In your problem the number of nodes is unbounded.) For example, given that the diameter is $2$ and the degree of each node is at most $3$, can you show that the network has at most $10$ nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bof hint pointed in the right direction. If both maximum degree and diameter are bounded you can find an upper bound for the number of nodes in any network of the sequence by doing a BFS from any node. With maximum degree $d$ and maximum diameter $k$ the total number of nodes can be at most the Moore bound: $$ n \leq 1 + d \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(d-1)^{i}$$